# How do I dynamically generate custom layouts in a parent layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-custom-view

When the activity loads, I want to generate a `ListView` wherein each item represents an object that contains a few things... a couple of strings and an image. If I weren't dynamically generating, I'd use something like

```
<include  layout="@layout/mycustomlayout" android:id="@+id/id" />
```

But I don't know how to do this dynamically. Each item in the ListView will probably end up being a RelativeLayout with contents, so I'd like to be able to do something like

```
MyRelativeLayout mrl = new MyRelativeLayout(attr1, attr2, attr2);
myListView.addFooterView(mrl);
```

My syntax above might not be right, but hopefully you get the concept. I want to define a RelativeLayout that I can easily add to a parent view in code. How would I go about this? Thanks.

Comment: See the ListView guide: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Comment: Thanks. I've been reading through that now. Stuff with loaders gets pretty complicated!

Comment: You don't have to use a `Loader` though, all you really have to do is set an adapter on the `ListView`. See the [AdapterView guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews).

Comment: @wiz3kid yeah I'm realizing that now. I guess a loader is more like for those lists that expand as your near the bottom? My ListView only needs to load data from a database. I might also use one that receives data from a dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You mean [CustomAdapter](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)?

First, create model that contains information of your List Item

Second, create custom adapter to inflate your model data to ListView

Finally, set your CustomAdapter on ListView.